# Can Hibernate OGM Persistence Provider be used with Spring-data-jpa?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-ogm

I really like the simplicity of spring data repository, however need to use hibernate as persistence provider for consistency and few other factors. (I am using mongodb but not using mongo template). Few things I noticed --

1. The HibernateJpaVendorAdapter uses "org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider"
2. The provider configured with the persistence unit ( ""org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence" ) is not considered, while constructing the EntityManagerFactory through a "org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"  bean.
3. If there are multiple persistence units configured for the project there is no apparent way to associate a persistence unit for a repository.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to use the configured persistence provider , instead of the default one ? The default provider is not working with mongodb.
2. Is there a way to associate a repository with a specific persistence unit ?

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution was to

1. implement
   `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.AbstractJpaVendorAdapter`   and
   return an instance of
   `org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence`  in
   `getPersistenceProvider()` method
2. Source the `jpaVendorAdapter` property for `entityManagerFactory`
   bean in spring config

However it still doesn't work good wherever there is reference to Pageable. Some design change can circumvent the issue.